# Keep or new baseboard?

Tags: baseboard

Putting in engineered floors where there was carpet before.  The carpet was put in before the baseboard I imagine to help hold the carpet down and avoid damaging baseboard during carpet install.  My question is: Should I remove and put in new baseboard or use the gap under the (above the floor)baseboard where the carpet was an the expansion space for the new wood floor?

Comment: What is the thickness of your new engineered floor, and what is the gap under the baseboard? It seems unlikely that the flooring would even fit under the base. (Plus, as noted below, remove/reinstall lets you get the base to the exact height.)

Answer (score 2):

I usually save the baseboard especially if it is real wood. Using caution it can be pulled and the finishing nails removed then after the floor is installed it can be put back in at the proper height for the new flooring.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished installing an engineered wood floor. I removed the baseboard and installed the floor. The expansion will be horizontal not vertical. I used the same baseboard and installed it right on top of the new floor with no gap. It's a great time to sand, stain, paint, touch up the baseboard before re installing it. 
I've actually seen an installation where the baseboard was left in place and the new floor installed around or under it. It really looked bad. Good luck.